# Program Transfer function and plot

Tags: plotting

I need to program a transfer function T(s) = 1/(s^2+Bs+1) and simulate the response of a unit step input of the Force for each value of B which i used in my range my B values are 4,2,1.8,1.4.......

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[(1)/(s^2 + Bs + 1), s];
tfm[I Range[4,2,1.8,1.4,1,0.6,0.2,0.02]]
Plot[Abs[tfm[I f]], {f, 0, 5}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you are not using Range correctly. Note the error: Range called with 8 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started. Added stiffness as well, which you could always set to 1.

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Manipulate[
 Module[{tf, y, t},
  tf = TransferFunctionModel[1/(s^2 + b s + k), s];

  (*specific time forces numeric, much faster*)
  y = OutputResponse[tf, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 50}]; 

  Plot[Evaluate@y, {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-.1, 2}}, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, {"t", "step response"}}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed, 
     ImageSize -> {300, 300}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1]
  ],

 (*controls*)
 Grid[{
   {Row[{"Damping B: ", PopupMenu[Dynamic[b], {0.02, 4, 2, 1.8, 1.4, 1, 0.6, 0.2}]}]},
   {Row[{"Stiffness k ", Manipulator[Dynamic[k, {k = #} &], {1, 5, .1}, 
       ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[k]}]}
   }
  ],
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {b, k}
 ]
```